# What should be the connection string for a default profile provider in windows azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I am using system.web.providers to implement basic authentication for my APIs in my windows azure project. This is my default connection string which am using

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-myProject.WebRole-20130117071735;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-myProject.WebRole-20130117071735.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

And in my AppData folder the .mdf file is being created. But when i deploy to my azure account am getting the following error.

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The system cannot find the file specified","ExceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","StackTrace":null}
```

I know the error doesnt give any information, but this is happening only for the APIs i have put the basic authentication so i guess the problem is that .mdf file isnt being created on cloud.

Any idea what the connection string should be when I deploy to cloud?

Comment: In Visual Studio, check the Properties of the .mdf file.  Ensure that Build Action = Content.  Otherwise the file won't get uploaded when you deploy.